# Search Display Controller displaying incorrect image

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode6, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have the following problem.
I have set up a search bar in a tableView written in swift. Each tableView cell has a label and an image. The problem is that when I try to search the searchDisplayController displays the right label but the wrong image (it displays the first image from the array).

when the app loads:

[image: when the app loads]

when I try to search:

[image: when I try to search]

As you can see the images start over from the beginning and the image view doesn't display the correct image for the iPhone cell.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

EDIT1: cellForRowAtIndexPath code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CustomCell

    var friend : FriendItem

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        friend = self.filteredFriends[indexPath.row]

    }
    else
    {
        friend = self.friendsArray[indexPath.row]

    }



    cell.label1.text = friend.name

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

    let item = friendsArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.setCell(item.name, image1: item.image)




    return cell

}
```

Comment: Can you please post your `cellForRowAtindexPath:` method?

Comment: pbush25, I provided the code thank you for the quick response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking item from friendsArray, but you should take if from filteredFriends array when you are searching. Try `cell.setCell(friend.name, image1: friend.image)`

Comment: That should work. Another option is to set the cell properties inside the `if...else` block.